# Where should I study contact mechanics (for introductory level)

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am MAthematics and MEchanical Engineering student and this is my senior year. For reserch and personal interest, I need to learn about contact mechanics. From where I should start and what is the prerequisites for this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Start with either Slaughter's or Barber's book on linear elasticity where they deal with Hertzian non-adhesive contact and the theory that leads to that.

Once you  know the basics, move on to K L Johnson's book on contact mechanics.  That will give you a good feel for adhesive contact too along with various solution methods.

Beyond a point you will have to start finding numerical solutions.  A good starting point is the book by Peter Wriggers (though I don't like the pedagogy in the book).

Once you know these three well, you can go to the scientific literature and start exploring the details of other solutions and approaches.

Comment: @Biswalt, thanks much for the 3 author names; have bookmarked!